# Java EJBQL Collection(List)

Tags: java, mysql, list, collections, ejbql

I begin to learn how to use collections/Entity Classes.
I just made the Entity classes from the Word (Default MySql Database) database.
I Wanna make a List of Citis and print it on the console, but i just had no ide how to do it. Please if someone would be kind to post the exact code how to do it, it will help a lot and i would figure out a lot from that.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are dozens of JPA tutorials on the web. We won't rewrite one just for you. Come back when you've tried something and have a concrete question.

Comment: Thanks for the help, even i was unintentional. JPA tutorials + Google. I didnt know how the heck to look for it.